# How do I show a "read more" link in my RSS feed?

Tags: feeds

I need to trim down my RSS feed so that people come back to the site to read the full article, how might I do this and is there a preferred / best method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what **Teasers** are for — the Teaser is the shortened version of the content, presented in RSS feeds (among other places, such as the site's front page).

When editing a node in Drupal 6, use the "**Split summary at cursor**" button to split the node's body into a Summary/"Teaser" and "Full view".

Then go to your site's `/admin/content/rss-publishing` page, and set "**Feed content**" to "**Title plus teaser**".

Additionally, on your site's `/admin/content/node-settings` page, you can configure the default length to use to split nodes.

For some additional customization, try the [Read More Link](http://drupal.org/project/ed_readmore) module (but be aware of [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/404490)), or Display Suite, as @Decipher mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) / [Node Displays](http://drupal.org/project/nd), gives you a nice interface for themeing the output of different displays (Full node, Teaser, etc) including the RSS output, so you can move the fields around, use [Custom Formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) to theme them, and add extra fields as required.

Nice easy way to customize your RSS feed as you need.

Plus the settings can be exported as a Feature.

Comment: The 'Read more' link isn't a field, so I think this solution is a little expensive for the small task. I prefer to recommend the Read More Link module.

Comment: Maybe that's true, but with Display Suite you can do a lot of generic tasks, so if you already have it you can use it to solve this issue, where as with the Read More Link module you can only solve the Read More Link problem. Sure, who needs Views, lets have an individual module for every list of data :|